# C++ private class member variables don't appear in the documentation

Tags: c++, doxygen

Class is documented as follows:

```
/**
 * @brief   Number representation
 */
class CNumber : public CElem
{
  /** @brief Holds true for negative values */
  bool    neg;
  ...
```

However, the variable documented in the code doesn't appear in the documentation (class brief shows fine...).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

It's private. Make it public or protected and it will show up, or configure Doxygen to show private members by setting the `EXTRACT_PRIVATE` tag to `YES` in the configuration file (which is usually "Doxyfile").